# Should this php function run recursively?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, database

Im having problems with a method in a class file:

```
    public static function getPageLeft($pid)
{
    self::_dbConnect();
    echo "now " .$pid;
    $pid--;
    echo " after ". $pid;
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM evening_pages WHERE id='".$pid."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($data);
    if($rows == 1){
        echo "  in  ";
        return $data;

    }elseif($pid != self::getMinPage()){
        self::getPageLeft($pid);
        echo " Current: " . $pid . " min: " .self::getMinPage();
    }
}
```

I have the echos in there for debug only, and im getting:

now 22 after 21now 21 after 20 Current: 21 min: 1

This code is to find the next page left in a database driven CMS in case the client deletes a row from the database, it finds the next lower value.

So page id is 22 that your on, looks for id 21 in database, if its not there it should return 0 for the rows and move on and try again but on id 20, but there IS an entry for id = 20.

Anyone spot any issues with the code?

Also getting this error when it tries to find a page which doesnt exist before the current page, eg on page 22 but there is no ID for 21:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/prelas/public_html/index.php on line 37

the code there is (line 37 is while):

```
    $getPageLeft = sql::getPageLeft($pid);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPageLeft)){
        $pageleft = $row['id'];
    }
```

Many thanks.

Just a quick edit: "  in  " never gets echoed, but yet when there is no deleted pages the navigation works fine.

Further edit: The code which makes use of the code (by like 37):

```
    $navigation = '<div id="direction">
      <span class="inNav"> <a href="index.php?pid='. $min .'">&lt;&lt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.php?pid='. $pageleft .'">&lt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span class="black">&bull;</span><span class="inNav">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.php?pid='. $pageright .'">&gt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.php">&gt;&gt;</a></span>
  </div>'
```

So you can see it uses $pageleft in there however when its dealing with blank pages the value is nothing (empty).

Comment: Well it does getPageLeft(22) which decrements to 21 and check the database... no entry. So it recursively call itself again getPageLeft(21), which decrements to 20, there's an entry, the code stops like it should. Where's the problem?

Comment: you should put the `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPageLeft)){` in the method, its part of the operation.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Not when you're simply counting the results. It's provided by MySQL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: @AlexBelanger Well when it finds that item (20) it isnt outputting it to the page (See the footnote "further edit:" at the bottom of the OP for the code on the page that calls the method.

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements, which would close the potential SQL injection vulnerability in the SQL query in `getPageLeft`.

Comment: Don't use [`or die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) when outputting HTML. You'll get invalid HTML. It's also inappropriate for the function to stop execution of the entire script. Instead, throw an exception and handle it at a higher level. Also, database error messages shouldn't be displayed to non-admin users; doing so [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don’t you write the SQL statement to get the next lower ID? For example:

```
 SELECT `id`
   FROM `evening_pages`
   WHERE `id` < ?
   ORDER BY `id` DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Or:

```
 SELECT MAX(`id`)
   FROM `evening_pages`
   WHERE `id` < ?
```

That way, you only have to check if something has been returned by the query. Less code, less overhead for database requests.

The mysql extension is being phased out. Learn about using mysqli or PDO, and read up on the dangers of [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

Comment: Best method I can think of too, if the IDs are primary auto increments, there's no reason to just check the first lower value than the current.

Comment: Oh thank you! I don't know why I didnt look at it that way! Thanks for this, could the same be applied for going 'right' along the id's (so increasing the id's? When i treid `id`>' it gives me a blank result (ie doesnt get anything) but it should work should it not? Thanks for taking the time to answer the OP :)